# Java XML Parse xPath not getting all child elements

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I have a very large XML file with a lot of elements.

I'm only interested in the cases which look like the example below. there's about 400 cases in the xml document I want to parse through the document and print out each element and name.

```
<cases>
<case>
    <id/>
    <title/>
    <type/>
    <priority/>
    <estimate/>
    <references/> 
    <custom>
        <functional_area/>
        <technology_dependence/>
        <reviewed/>
        <steps_completed>
        </steps_completed>
        <preconds> </preconds>
        <steps_seperated>
            <step>
                <index/>
                <content>
                </content>
                <expected>
                </expected>
            </step>
            <step>
                <index/>
                <content>
                </content>
                <expected>
                </expected>
            </step>
            <step>
            </steps_seperated>
        </custom>
    </case>
```

at the moment my code works fine up until "steps_seperated"  where it stops and goes onto the next case.

my code looks like this  (MVCE BELOW)

I can't work out why it stops after "steps_seperated" and starts a new case

a second issue I've noticed is it only displays out 10 or so cases (im not sure if this is because I'm running it in netbeans )

any help would be very much appreciated thank you

p.s

mvce

```
 public void printCaseElements(NodeList list){

    for(int i = 0 ;i <list.getLength();i++){
            Element el = (Element) list.item(i);
            System.out.println("tag: " + el.getNodeName());

            if(el.getFirstChild().getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
            {
                System.out.println("Inner Value: "+ el.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                System.out.println("________________________________________________________________________");

                NodeList children = el.getChildNodes();
                for(int k = 0; k < children.getLength(); k++){
                    Node child = children.item(k);

                    if (child.getNodeType() != Node.TEXT_NODE){
                        System.out.println("child tag: "+ child.getNodeName());


                        if(child.getFirstChild().getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE){
                            System.out.println("inner child value :" + child.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());

                            System.out.println("____________________________________________________________________________________________");

                                         }
                                     }
                                 }
                            }

                        }
```

P.P.S

I think the issue may be when I use xPath

```
    DOMParser parser =new DOMParser() ;
    InputSource source = new InputSource(path) ;
    try {
        parser.parse(source);
        Element docElement = parser.getDocument().getDocumentElement();
        XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
       XPathExpression  expression =xPath.compile("//case/*");
       NodeList list =(NodeList) expression.evaluate(docElement,XPathConstants.NODESET);
       DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
       Document newDoc = documentBuilder.newDocument();
       Element newElement = newDoc.createElement("cases");
       newDoc.appendChild(newElement);
       for(int i =0 ; i <list.getLength(); i++){
          Node n = newDoc.importNode(list.item(i), true);
          newElement.appendChild(n);
       }
```

when I changed ("//case/*")  to ("//steps_seperated/*") it showed all the elements below steps separated.  but not the elements before  steps_seperated

Comment: can you please create an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)???

Comment: hi im sorry I don't know what a MVCE is?

Comment: follow the link please....

Comment: Ok give me a minute i'll edit my post to show one method that takes in a NodeList up one method that should be

Comment: I've edited the post it's now set up as a single method that takes in a nodelist and souts  the elements but for some reason it gets stuck at "separated_steps"

Comment: @BeginnerJavaDev how about using one of these xpath : `//case//*` or `//case/descendant::*`?